# Dispatch a function with Redux and TypeScript not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to dispatch a function using Redux and Typescript in React, but I'm getting this error:

```
Argument of type '(dispatch: Dispatch) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AnyAction'
```

Function 1:

```
const postProducts = (origin: string) => {
   return (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
      dispatch(initProducts(origin))
   }
}
```

Function 2:

```
export const initProducts = (origin: string) => {
   return (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
      if (origin !== 'load') {
         dispatch(setToastify(errorMsg))
      }
   }
}
```

Function 3:

```
export const setToastify = (toastifyDetails: string, open = true) => {
   return {
      type: ActionType.SET_TOASTIFY,
      toastify: toastifyDetails,
      open: open
   }
}
```

P.S. I know nowadays I should be using Redux Toolkit, but this project is just for educational purposes.

Answer (score 3):

Your `dispatch` functions types are not aware that you have the `thunk` middleware active.

Please follow the [TypeScript Quick Start](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript) tutorial to see how to set up your store in a way that the types are in place correctly. You will end up with some kind of `AppDispatch` type to use instead of the plain `Dispatch` type here.

Answer (score 1):

for each action you should have an action type defined. for `setToastify`:

```
import { ActionType } from "../action-types";

export interface SetToastifyAction {
  type: ActionType.SET_TOASTIFY;
  payload: {
    toastifyDetails: string;
    open: boolean;
  };
```

your `setToastify` should be like this:

```
export const setToastify = (toastifyDetails: string, open = true):SetToastifyAction => {
   return {
      type: ActionType.SET_TOASTIFY,
      toastify: toastifyDetails,
      open: open
   }
}
```

you might have more than one action. Define type:

```
export type Action =
  | SetToastifyAction
  | AnotherAction
```

herAction

Then use this in your reducer:

```
  (state: YourStateType = initialState, action: Action):  YourStateType => {
```

Comment: That's a actually a very old style of doing Redux with TypeScript and we do not recommend having individual action types any more - you should not need to write such an implementation detail by hand. See https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today for more details and https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/typescript for instructions how to set up the types according to the current recommendations.